# Eigenvectors of convex combination of projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are two $k$-dimensional linear subspaces. Let $\Pi_X, \Pi_Y$ denote the orthogonal projections onto $X$ and $Y$, respectively, with respect to the standard dot product.

Question: Let $0 < \mu < 1$. 
What are the eigenvectors of the matrix $[\mu \Pi_X + (1-\mu) \Pi_Y]$?

Geometrically, $v$ is an eigenvector if the following is true. The components of $\Pi_X v$ and $\Pi_Y v$ orthogonal to $v$ cancel after taking their weighted average. This seems geometrically simple enough that I thought there might be a simple explicit formula to find such eigenvectors. But I haven't found it.

Can anyone offer any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that there is a simple formula. For an example, suppose we take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then if we find the eigenvectors of $\mu A+(1-\mu)B,$ we get $$x_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3\mu^{2}-4\mu+2}-\mu\\\sqrt{2}(\mu-1)\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad x_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}-\mu-\sqrt{3\mu^{2}-4\mu+2}\\\sqrt{2}(\mu-1)\end{bmatrix}.$$ Also, there is some reason to think that we would have to solve $n$-degree polynomial equations if $A$ and $B$ were $n\times n$ matrices, so the problem quickly becomes impossible, if you're looking for analytic formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I suppose I might have been overly optimistic.